# Update MP3 Player bar

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to update the player bar as the mp3 plays.The bar should represent the length of the song and update to show how much of the song has played so far.

Kinda lost bytesLoaded bytesTotal or?

Assume the bar has a width of 200px;

I've tried dividing this and that.No Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    public class Engine extends Sprite
    {
        private var _sound:Sound;
        private var _soundBar:Sprite;
        private var _soundChannel:SoundChannel;
        public function Engine() 
        {
            addSoundChannel();
            drawSoundBar();
            //load sound
            loadSound("sound.mp3");
        }

        private function addSoundChannel():void
        {
            _soundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        }

        private function drawSoundBar():void
        {
            //draw box 200px x 10px with a red fill
            _soundBar = new Sprite();
            _soundBar.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            _soundBar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 10);
            _soundBar.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(_soundBar);
            _soundBar.x = (stage.stageWidth/2) - (_soundBar.width/2);
            _soundBar.y = (stage.stageHeight/2) - (_soundBar.height/2);
        }

        private function loadSound(url:String):void
        {
            var toLoad:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            _sound = new Sound();
            _sound.load(toLoad);
            _sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function soundLoaded(evt:Event):void
        {
            trace("loaded");
            _soundChannel = _sound.play();
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkSound, false, 0, true);
            _soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundComplete, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function checkSound(evt:Event):void
        {
            //adjust scaleX from 0 to 1 based on sound position
            _soundBar.scaleX = _soundChannel.position / _sound.length;
        }

        private function soundComplete(evt:Event):void
        {
            trace("done");
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkSound);
        }

    }

}
```

`SoundChannel.position` grabs the current position in milliseconds while `Sound.length` is the sound length in milliseconds.

Comment: Right, I'm assuming he's capable of checking progress via an `ENTER_FRAME` event, which seems legitimate seeing as he's worked with loader progress before. I added a few comments to help bridge the gap a bit, but I don't see how much further I can go at this point.

Comment: He doesn't even know how to get the percentage from bytesLoaded and bytesTotal.

Comment: I don't see why just giving me code did not help.I understood everything perectly.Like I said in my post I just did not how to get the percentage.Does'nt mean I don't know how to use eventListeners and use the drawing API. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely. Don't judge a book by its cover.